# Toggle() binded to WP menu item prevents clicking on sub-menu items

Tags: jquery, wordpress, menu, toggle

On [my WP page](http://blacksoap.fr/shooga/) I have a custom menu with one of the items ("COLLECTIONS") having a sub-menu, which is hidden by default and displayed when clicking on "COLLECTIONS" through this code:

```
$( 'li.item_collection' ).toggle(function() {
    $( 'li.item_collection .sub-menu' ).slideDown( { duration: 200, easing: 'easeInOutExpo' } );
    }, function() {
    $( 'li.item_collection .sub-menu' ).slideUp(100);
    });
```

Problem is, I can't click on sub-menu items because doing so triggers the toggle() binded to "COLLECTIONS" items. How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stop the click event bubbling up the DOM tree:

```
$( 'li.item_collection .sub-menu' ).click(function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[More info on e.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/)

I would also change your toggle code to the following so it only toggles the sub-menu of the clicked item:

```
$( 'li.item_collection' ).toggle(function() {
    $(this).find( '.sub-menu' ).slideDown( { duration: 200, easing: 'easeInOutExpo' } );
}, function() {
    $(this).find( '.sub-menu' ).slideUp(100);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a more specific selector such as id in order to only target the highest level expandable menu. Currently your code binds to all li.item_collection which applies to the sub menu ass well. Another way would be to get the class of the clicked element and check the class does not contain sub-menu or checking the child elements of the clicked element.

the easiest would be the id selector:

```
<li class="item_collection" id="highLevelMenu">
   ......
</li>
```

and in that case jquery should be:

```
$( '#highLevelMenu' ).toggle(function() {
  $( 'li.item_collection .sub-menu' ).slideDown( { duration: 200, easing: 'easeInOutExpo' } );
}, function() {
  $( 'li.item_collection .sub-menu' ).slideUp(100);
});
```

Comment: this will still have the same problem as `.sub-menu` is a part of `#highLevelMenu` so clicking it will still trigger the toggle